# rails 4 with rack-offline issues

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Recently i have posted this issue, so then i tried another way to cache the javascript and css, things like

This is routes.rb

```
offline = Rack::Offline.configure  do 

cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.css")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.offline.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.tmpl.min.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("json.js")

network "/"
end
get "/application.manifest" => offline
```

This is the application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/application.manifest">
<head>
<title>OfflineTest</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

This is index.html.erb

```
Listing

<%= form_for Item.new do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.submit "Add" %>
</p>
<% end %>

<script type="text/html" id="item_template">
<li>${name}</li>
</script>
<ol id="items">
<li><em>Loading items...</em></li>
</ol>
```

This is application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.tmpl.min
//= require jquery.offline
//= require json
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){
if ($.support.localStorage) {
$(window.applicationCache).bind("error", function() {
  console.log("There was an error when loading the cache manifest.");
});
if (!localStorage["pendingItems"]) {
  localStorage["pendingItems"] = JSON.stringify([]);
}
$.retrieveJSON("/items.json", function(data) {
  var pendingItems = $.parseJSON(localStorage["pendingItems"]);
  $("#items").html($("#item_template").tmpl(data.concat(pendingItems)));
});

} else {
alert("Try a different browser.");
}
});
```

and added the gem

```
gem "rack-offline"
```

after this when i go for the application.manifest , it seems like

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 1ad140903542ef1549ddf41cb57e9105786a8b344d7fab9278323e9402e61d14
/assets/application.css
/assets/application.js
/assets/jquery.offline.js
/assets/jquery.tmpl.min.js
/assets/json.js

NETWORK: 
/
```

So the problem coming here like, when i stop the server and check, its not loading the JS and CSS files, that means not loading the data in view, but its working with online, actually i have tried the same way in rails 4.0.2 and ruby 2.0.0 that worked. but when i comes to rails 4.1.6 and ruby 2.1.2 its not working with the offline mode. is there any issues with my configuration and all these?

Comment: Got the solution and resolved, that was the issue with Jquery.js

Comment: I am just wondering why you did not post a detailed solution to your problem after solving it. Because I am facing the same problem now.Anyway why did you ask the question? Please help, tell us what you did. I am using rails 4.1.6 and ruby 2.1.2

Comment: i think, you need to add this one 
cache  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.js") to routes.rb, otherwise it will not work all other js files